# F# async lambda interop with C# async model

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, pulumi

I have such a piece of code (C#, Pulumi), which I want to translate to F#:

```
var registryInfo = repo.RegistryId.Apply(async (id) =>
        {
            var creds = await GetCredentials.InvokeAsync(new GetCredentialsArgs {RegistryId = id});
            var decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(creds.AuthorizationToken);
            var decoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decodedData);

            var parts = decoded.Split(':');

            return new ImageRegistry
            {
                Server = creds.ProxyEndpoint,
                Username = parts[0],
                Password = parts[1],
            };
        });
```

What I have managed to do so far is:

```
let registryInfo = repo.RegistryId.Apply (fun id -> async {
let! creds = GetCredentialsArgs ( RegistryId = id) |> GetCredentials.InvokeAsync |> Async.AwaitTask
let decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String creds.AuthorizationToken
let decoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString decodedData
let parts = decoded.Split ':'
return ImageRegistry( Server = input creds.ProxyEndpoint, Username= input parts.[0], Password = input parts.[1])
} 
)
```

The problem is that the code above in F# returns `Output<Async<ImageRegistry>>`, while C# code returns expected `Output<ImageRegistry>`. I am doing a transition from C# to F# (to extend my skills), but I cannot handle this case myself. How this should be properly done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library `Pulumi.FSharp` provides a useful helper `Outputs.applyAsync` for this:

```
open Pulumi.FSharp

let registryInfo =
    repo.RegistryId |>
    Outputs.applyAsync (fun id -> async {
        let! creds = GetCredentialsArgs ( RegistryId = id) |> GetCredentials.InvokeAsync |> Async.AwaitTask
        let decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String creds.AuthorizationToken
        let decoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString decodedData
        let parts = decoded.Split ':'
        return ImageRegistry( Server = input creds.ProxyEndpoint, Username= input parts.[0], Password = input parts.[1])
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing too much about the Pulimu API's I'd guess that `Apply` is expecting a `Task<T>`.

You can convert from F# async to Task using `Async.StartAsTask` like so:

```ml
let registryInfo = repo.RegistryId.Apply (fun id -> async {
//snip
return ImageRegistry( Server = input creds.ProxyEndpoint, Username= input parts.[0], Password = input parts.[1])
} |> Async.StartAsTask
)
```

Although if you are working with Task's you might be better using the `task` computation expression over the native F# `async` using a library such as [Ply](https://github.com/crowded/ply) (as of writing the native task support is still [in development](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/581)).

Comment: Still in development, but pretty much ready. Guess we'll see it soon.